# CSS absolute position for menu

Tags: html, css

I have made this menu but I have a problem :

HTML :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="layer">
         <div class="banner">
            <div class="header-one">
               <div class="left-header">
                  <div class="border-l"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="middle-header">
               </div>
               <div class="right-header">
                  <div class="border-r"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-two"></div>
         </div>
              <!-- <div class="page-in"></div> -->
      </div>

      <footer>
         <div class="footer"></div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 400;
}

.header-one {
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.85);
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.left-header {
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.border-l {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 2px;
    top: 100%;
    right: 60%;
    left: 0;
}

.middle-header {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 5px;
}

.right-header {
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.border-r {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 2px;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 60%;
}

.header-two {
    height: 25px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.85);
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-top: 0;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.7);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #666;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

.page-in {
  height: 400px;
}

.footer {
  height: 10px;
    background-color: #404040;
    border-top: solid;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7ok6qjb/

You can see the problem by uncommenting the div. The menu is moving by itself.

When the page is loading there is no overflow, but when the page is loaded there is a scroll bar. The problem is that the menu is moving to the left to consider the size of the scroll bar.

I don't want my menu to move and I want it to have a position that is not dependant on the scroll bar.

I don't know how to make this. I already tried with "absolute" but this is acting like fixed and the menu is following the content (and is above)

Any tips would be welcome!

Comment: Is is supposed to be like this? https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/7m0x4qce/6/

Comment: Thanks for answering but unfortunetaly this is not. I updated my post to accurate the view. You can now see the problem clearly by uncommenting the div. You can see that the menu is moving.